# Which library/framework can be used for this specific project?

Tags: c#, c++

I have a project, but I don't know which library that I could use for this project:
*Project requirement*

1. Log into hotmail.com
2. Click on each email individually and take a specific link out of the email.
3. Copy and add the link i want into a txt file.

I've used to try Watir with Ruby, however I would like to try C++ and C# libraries this time. Plus, non-commercial please since I'm still a student. Any idea?

Thank you,

Comment: I haven't done it, so this is just a thought, but since Outlook and Outlook Express (aka Windows Mail) both can connect to Hotmail directly, you may be able to leverage that object library to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't think of this in terms of logging into hotmail.com and clicking.  Instead, think of it as retrieving email programmatically.  Hotmail supports two standard protocols for this: POP3 and Exchange.  If you're programming this on Windows, and since you tagged the question C#, I suggest using C# to access the Exchange API, which is introduced here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd637749%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx

You should be able with fairly little effort to open the emails and extract the links you want.  If the Exchange API doesn't work out, just use POP3, which will be programmable from any platform.